# Established as a rule through experimentation or statistics

Tags: vocabulary

There's a word that's slipped my mind. It's used for example to qualify findings through tests or statistics as opposed to formulae or hard science. Any ideas?

Comment: There is also *inductive reasoning*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_reasoning

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you thinking of [empirical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/empirical)?

Comment: Yes, that's the word I was looking for. A broad vocabulary is a good thing but it needs to be maintained through regular usage.

Comment: In his latest book *The Beginning of Infinity*, David Deutsch makes the compelling case that the status of **empiricism** in Western Civilisation since the Enlightenment is the most significant thing that has ever happened in Earth's 4.5-billion-year history. So we should all make more effort to retrieve the word as deftly as Peter.

Answer (score 1):

[Peter has a good suggestion](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28633/established-as-a-rule-through-results-statistics/28634#28634) but I will add that we also say *"it is an experimental fact that..."*.